# Change all cells marked X into cell value shown in column P

Tags: formula, divide

I need an easy way to convert all X's in a column into the value shown in a cell.

Basically we want to sell multiple products to a client with a target order value split amongst the relevant products - I have done a CountA formula to show how many columns are not blank. Then I did a simple divide to divide the total value over the columns that are not blank (if there are 2 columns marked X then it would be 10,000 / 2 - assuming the target value is 10k) Now I need to change all the X's into the figure shown in the cell as shown in the pic.

I cant for the life of me think of an easy way of doing it but sureley there is?

[Screen shot of sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOP6d.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 sets of columns.  Your first set has the X's and the blanks to mark which categories are applicable.  The second set has the calculated values for the selected categories.

In the value columns, you can use a formula like the following for the first data row and first category:

```
=IF(E2 = "x", $D2, 0)
```

Assuming "D" is your "Dvided total" column, and "E" is your "Dairy & S..." column, and "2" is your first data row.